# Using 'get_template_directory_uri' correctly

Tags: theme-development

I have a woo-commerce child theme set up. In the functions.php file I am loading an additional tab. The function which loads the tab looks like this:

```
   function woo_finance_tab_content() {

    echo '<h2>Additional Tab</h2>';

}
```

I'm attempting to load several php files, within this function. What is the correct way to do this though? If I have 'test.php' which I want to load inside the function, is it simply a case of using:

```
echo "get_template_directory_uri(/woocommerce/single-product/test.php)";
```

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` doesn't take any parameter. Try appending strings after it. See [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()`, as the name suggests, gets the *URI* of the theme. You want the filesystem path, which is [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory):

```
<?php require get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product/test.php' ?>
```

Better yet, use the WordPress template loading system:

```
<?php locate_template( 'woocommerce/single-product/test.php', true /* Locate AND load the file */ ) ?>
```